# Deserializing a nested object using Django Rest Framework ModelSerializer

Tags: json, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have this JavaScript code in the client sending a vacation object to the server:

```
         const vacation = {
            employee: currentEmployee,
            startDate: form.querySelector('#start-date').value,
            endDate: form.querySelector('#end-date').value,
            vacationReason: form.querySelector('#reason').value,
            status: 'P',
        };

        const newData = new FormData();
        newData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', getCSRFToken());
        newData.append('vacation', JSON.stringify(vacation));

        const postReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

        postReq.open(
            'POST',
            '/vacations/vacation-list'
        )

        postReq.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (postReq.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                if (postReq.status === 201)
                    window.location.replace('/vacations');
                else
                    prompt('BAD REQUEST.');
            }
        }

        postReq.send(newData);
```

The problem is that when I try to use `VacationSerializer` in the `vacation_list` view,

```
serializer = VacationSerializer(data=json.loads(request.POST.get('vacation'))
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
```

I get `serializer.errors`: an 'employee' object already exists with this id.
And it's essentially meant to be a vacation for an existing employee! I could not find a way to deserialize using `ModelSerializer` with an existing object as part of the referencing object.

These are my `Model`s:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )

    MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('S', 'Single'),
        ('M', 'Married'),
    )

    id = models.IntegerField(default=20230000, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(default="mail@gmail.com")
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='M')
    maritalStatus = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES, null=True)
    availableVacationDays = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    approvedVacationDays = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    salary = models.IntegerField()
    birthDay = models.DateField(null=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"Employee: {self.name}"
    


class Vacation(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('P', 'Pending'),
        ('A', 'Approved'),
        ('R', 'Rejected'),
    )
    employee = models.ForeignKey(
        Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vacation')
    startDate = models.DateField()
    endDate = models.DateField()
    vacationReason = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='P')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.employee} wants to take a vacation from {self.startDate} to {self.endDate}."
```

These are my `ModelSerializer`s:

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'name', 'email', 'phoneNumber', 'address', 'gender', 'maritalStatus', 'availableVacationDays', 'approvedVacationDays', 'salary', 'birthDay']


class VacationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    employee = EmployeeSerializer()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Vacation
        fields = ['id', 'employee', 'startDate', 'endDate', 'vacationReason', 'status']
        
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        employee_data = validated_data.pop('employee')
        vacation = Vacation.objects.create(**validated_data)
        vacation.employee = Employee.objects.get(id=employee_data['id'])
        return vacation
```

I tried the above overriding of the create method, but it does not seem to change anything.
I found that the problem is at `is_valid()` method, for which I didn't find any useful resources about changing its behavior.

#### Update

I think the `ModelSerializer` just does not fit in this context, other methods show better performance without much headaches.

Comment: please also add the code of the model classes